# is a SVM invariant to Skewness and Kurtosis?

Tags: classification, svm, skewness

I have data that is highly positively skewed, and I want to train a SVM (LibSVM) Classifier on the data with 3 classes... 
my question is, does skewness and/or curtosis affect performance of a SVM classifier? or is it invariant to those statistic measurements? and which other classifiers are invariant of statistical measures, and which ones does affect them?